# Returning meaningful HTTP responses in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I feel it's a good idea to return meaningful HTTP responses but I'm trying to come up with the right approach to handle that.

In my ASP.NET Core Web API app, the endpoints i.e. API action methods, simply receive a request, call my business layer for a response and return the response.

At the business layer, I check to see if the request is authorized or not. If it's not authorized, I throw an exception that incdicates the type of exception i.e. unauthorized request but in those cases, my API endpoint simply returns an `HTTP 500`. I'd rather return an `HTTP 401`.

Question is how to transfer my lower level exceptions to `HTTP` status codes.

Two questions:

1. Is it worth trying to capture the type of exception that occurred at a lower level in the app and try to translate it to `HTTP` responses or should I simply let my API return an `HTTP 500`?
2. If it's worth it, how do I handle it?

Comment: SO is wrong place to have discussion on 5xx vs. 4xx vs. error message in response.

Comment: @Sam - I agree with Alexei, this question is off topic here. However, if you reword the question to ask "how" to do it instead of "should I" do it, this would be a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your controller extends Microsoft.AspNet.MVC.Controller you'll have inherited some methods that do what you need like OK, Forbidden, BadRequest, ObjectResult, etc.. So in the case you've described above you could do something like

```
public async IActionResult DoMyThing()
{
    try 
    {
        return ObjectResult(await DoMyInternalCall());
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //FigureOut the Exception type indications a security violation
        return Forbidden() 
    }
    ....
```

Personally I prefer to build APIs that return a status instead of throwing an exception which makes this all a bit cleaner especially now that we have tuples. So something like

```
public async IActionResult DoMyThing()
{
        var (Status status, string myThing) = await DoMyInternalCall();
        switch(status)
        {
             case Status.OK: return ObjectResult(myThing);
                             break;

             case Status.AccessDenied: return Forbidden();
                                       break;

             case Status.NotFound: return Notfound();

             ...
```

That's just a taste thing though - I don't judge. The point is, Microsoft.AspNet.MVC.Controller  has built in methods to let you return valid HTTP status codes along with data.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**A Web API should strive to never return a `500` status code** (Internal Server Error). If it does, then there is something wrong with the code you have written.

Having said that, you shouldn't be throwing an exception with the intent to send back a status code is a rather poor way to handle requests -- i.e. by doing a blanket catch all and masking it with some nice status code to the client.

> You should run all your validation and logic on the request and send back your choice of any of the `4xx` status codes.

Essentially, for a Web API the status codes should be

```
2XX -- Success //(ex: OK, created, no content, etc)
3XX -- Redirection //(ex: renamed an API's path/url to a new one)
4XX -- Client Error
       ex:
           405 //Method Not Allowed (ex: client sent a DELETE request to your API)
           409 //Conflict
           415 //Unsupported Media Type (ex: client requests for XML -- yuck! no!)
           416 //Range Not Suitable (ex: client asked for a million records)
           422 //Unpronounceable Entity (ex: client sent something invalid in the body)
5XX -- Server Error //(ex: a well written Web API will NEVER error! )
```

**However, if you really do have an exception, then a `500` error code is correct -- that means you wrote bad code (refer back to my first point).**

Comment: Are you saying I should check to see if a user is authorized at the API level and not at business layer?

Comment: @Sam I can't be sure based on the information provided, but in practice you should be trying to validate at every layer. Never assuming that data between layers is valid.

Comment: @Sam generally the earlier you can stop a **bad request** from making it's way down your request pipeline (passing further down each layer) the better. Meaning that most exceptions are unlikely to occur on the first place.

Comment: Since you wanted to express you opinion on off-topic part of the question :)... I completely disagree with it - 5xx simply means "an error that is not callers' fault". There are plenty of reasons why call to somewhat complex service can fail - like out of memory, timeouts on external calls, mis-configured dependent services,...

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this idea of throwing exceptions at all. A 500 is a sign that  there is something really wrong with your own code.

So, let's say that your business layer is checking to see if a user is authorised. What I would do is create a method which checks the authorisation, have that method return a simple Boolean response for example. Then your controller checks the flag, if it's false, return 401, job done. This is a much better way of communicating between your business layer and api layer.

Obviously I have no way of knowing how your business layer is built, but keep it simple, keep it clear, don't try to trap any exceptions, deal with everything cleanly and return appropriate HTTP codes.

The business layer should not care at all about the api, should not deal with HTTP codes, basically  this means you are not leaking abstractions everywhere and you keep things in the layer where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole host of HTTP response codes of course, and just because a request couldn't be properly handled doesn't necessarily mean it's a 500 Internal Server error.  What if someone requests an update to a non-existent object?  That wouldn't fall under the range of a 500 (unsure offhand exactly which would work - 4xx I'd guess, but a handy list of common HTTP responses while you're working on this would be recommended).  I generally feel that 500s are for "uh oh, something happened on our end and we don't know what..." type of thing.  For most other cases there's a more appropriate response.

With that said, I feel that exceptions are best generalized as they move further toward the top layers.  Entity Framework throws some esoteric exception, the data access layer wraps it up in a slightly more generic DataAccessException (with the original as the inner, of course), the repository maybe handles it even more generically, and by the time it gets to your controller for response handling, you should only have a handful of "actual" exceptions that ought to need to be handled.  Return something fairly generic, log the nested exceptions on the server, and go from there?

My 2cents